# Most present color for each Year - pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a column "Date" and a column "Color" and I need to identify the max occurrences of the color column for each year.

| Date | Color |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-26 13:48:19 | White |
| 2015-01-27 13:48:19 | Yellow |
| 2022-01-28 13:48:19 | Blue |
| 2018-01-29 13:48:19 | White |
| 2017-01-30 13:48:19 | Yellow |

Let's assume the dataset is big and it varies a lot in different colors and dates. How would you identify the max color occurrences for each year, and how would you plot it?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
final=df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.year)['Color'].agg(pd.Series.mode)
```

if you want to see totals:

```
final=df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.year)['Color'].agg([pd.Series.mode,'count'])
```

Comment: Thank you Clegane, this helps. The issue I still encounter is that it counts but only the rows, not the ocurrences of different colors. Any idea how to count every color by itself, grouped by the year like you did above?

Comment: Can you add the output you expect as a table or code to the question ?

Comment: The output would be something like:

2015 - Green - 50 (considering it counted the "Green" color 50 times and it was the max amount of colors counted for that year)
2016 - Blue - 70 (considering it counted the "Blue" color 70 times and it was the max amount of colors counted for that year)
2017 - Yellow - 55 (considering it counted the "Yellow" color 55 times and it was the max amount of colors counted for that year)
2018 - Red - 15 (considering it counted the "Red" color 15 times and it was the max amount of colors counted for that year)